Renko Indicator - 1% block size defined brick size, and 1s timeframe
I am scripting this Renko indicator. It uses basically WaveTrend by Lazybear as a start: when wt1 crosses wt2, beyond the -60/60 threshold, and with a correct green/red candle accordingly, it will:

plot a Buy/Sell Shape with background.
reset a variable called lowestLow/highestHigh

Whenever a candle closes beyond these values lowestLow[1]/highestHigh[1] (also plotted), it should send a TradingView alert (alertcondition)
//@version=5
indicator("Attempt1", shorttitle="Attempt1", overlay=true)

n1 = input(10, "Channel Length")
n2 = input(21, "Average Length")
obLevel1 = input(60, "Over Bought Level 1")
obLevel2 = input(53, "Over Bought Level 2")
osLevel1 = input(-60, "Over Sold Level 1")
osLevel2 = input(-53, "Over Sold Level 2")

ap = hlc3 
esa = ta.ema(ap, n1)
d = ta.ema(math.abs(ap - esa), n1)
ci = (ap - esa) / (0.015 * d)
tci = ta.ema(ci, n2)

wt1 = tci
wt2 = ta.sma(wt1,4)

//plot(0, color=color.gray)
//plot(obLevel1, color=color.red)
//plot(osLevel1, color=color.green)
//plot(obLevel2, color=color.red, style=plot.style_stepline)
//plot(osLevel2, color=color.green, style=plot.style_stepline)

//plot(wt1, title="linhaverde", color=color.green)
//plot(wt2, title="pontos", color=color.red, style=plot.style_stepline)

buyexit = ((ta.crossover(wt1, wt2)) and (wt1 < -60)) and close > open
sellexit = ((ta.crossunder(wt1,wt2)) and (wt1 > 60)) and close < open

// Track highest high
var float highestHigh = na
var float lowestLow = na


// Update highest high
if buyexit
    highestHigh := high

if high > highestHigh
    highestHigh := high

if sellexit
    lowestLow := low

if low < lowestLow
    lowestLow := low

// Plot highest high
plot(highestHigh, color=color.blue, linewidth=2, title="Highest High After Event")
plot(lowestLow, color=color.rgb(230, 29, 29) , linewidth=2, title="Highest High After Event")
//Plot Buy/Sell based on wavetrend LZBR
plotshape(buyexit , title="BuyShape", style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.aqua, text="B", textcolor=color.white)
plotshape(sellexit , title="SellShape", style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, text="S", textcolor=color.black)

Cruzouacima = (close > highestHigh[1])
Cruzouabaixo = (close < lowestLow[1])

plotshape(Cruzouacima, title="BuyShape", style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=na, text="B", textcolor=color.white)
plotshape(Cruzouabaixo, title="SellShape", style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=na, text="S", textcolor=color.white)

alertcondition(Cruzouacima, "Buy" , "Buy")
alertcondition(Cruzouabaixo, "Sell" , "Sell")


var table table1 = table.new(position.top_right, 3, 3)
table.cell(table1, 0, 0, str.tostring("HH"), bgcolor=color.new(color.blue, 0))
table.cell(table1, 1, 0, str.tostring("LL"), bgcolor=color.new(color.blue, 0))
table.cell(table1, 2, 0, str.tostring('WT1'), bgcolor=color.new(color.blue, 0))
table.cell(table1, 0, 1, str.tostring(highestHigh), bgcolor=color.new(color.blue, 0))
table.cell(table1, 1, 1, str.tostring(lowestLow), bgcolor=color.new(color.blue, 0))
table.cell(table1, 2, 1, str.tostring(wt1, '#.#'), bgcolor=color.new(color.blue, 0))
table.cell(table1, 0, 2, str.tostring(highestHigh[1]), bgcolor=color.new(color.blue, 0))
table.cell(table1, 1, 2, str.tostring(lowestLow[1]), bgcolor=color.new(color.blue, 0))
table.cell(table1, 2, 2, str.tostring(wt2, '#.#'), bgcolor=color.new(color.blue, 0))

It all looks like it is working fine, until eventually one candle sticks out, making a higher high, or making a lower low (BUT VERY far away from crossing the var lowestLow/highestHigh), and still sends an alert, out of nowhere, and funny enough, WITHOUT Plotting the Buy/Sell Shape.
I even made a table to identify any change of the var's lowestLow/highestHigh, and those remains steady. I have no idea why these alerts are being triggered. And, if triggered, why are there no Buy/Sell Shapes attached to it.
